# angular production build FatalProcessOutOfMemory error

Tags: angular

When I run production build in angular app, I'm getting  `FatalProcessOutOfMemory` error.

### [image]

- angular 6.0.8
- type script :2.7.2

Comment: Please go through https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618 if that helps your cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For production build, run following command:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 1):

For prod build, run following command:

> node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build
>   --target production

For more optimization flags, below command:

It has inbuilt cache busting and other goodies:

> node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build
>   --target production --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to AppData->Roming->npm

Open `ng.cmd` file and replace with below code :

```
  @IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" "--max_old_space_size=8192" "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node "--max_old_space_size=8192" "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
)
```

and save it.