# getting an error on Build Angular 8 App with "ng build" command

Tags: angular, heap-memory

**Below is the error Log** **while application is still running with ng-serve But ng build throws that error**

> Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading... Browserslist:
>   caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
>   Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm
>   update` <--- Last few GCs ---> [27080:00000200BDB13F70] 24667 ms:
>   Scavenge 1395.4 (1423.4) -> 1394.9 (1424.4) MB, 7.2 / 0.0 ms (average
>   mu = 0.104, current mu = 0.007) allocation failure
>   [27080:00000200BDB13F70] 26796 ms: Mark-sweep 1396.0 (1424.4) ->
>   1395.6 (1424.4) MB, 2125.6 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.057, current mu = 0.007) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed <--- JS stacktrace ---> ==== JS stack trace
>   ========================================= 0: ExitFrame [pc: 000002DCE045C5C1] 1: StubFrame [pc: 000002DCE0413770] Security
>   context: 0x018f5931e6e9  2: visitQueue [000003747B766FE1]
>   [D:\Bentley\DesignValidationUI\source\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:~96]
>   [pc=000002DCE078F352](this=0x01f17be0d789 ,queue=0x01f17be0d7e9 ) 3: visitSingle
>   [000003747B766FA9] [D:\Bentley\DesignValidationUI\source... FATAL
>   ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed -
>   JavaScript heap out of memory 1: 00007FF703AEC6AA
>   v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506 2:
>   00007FF703AC7416 node::MakeCallback+4534 3: 00007FF703AC7D90
>   node_module_register+2032 4: 00007FF703DE189E
>   v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846 5: 00007FF703DE17CF
>   v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639 6: 00007FF703FC7F94
>   v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620 7: 00007FF703FBEF76
>   v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550 8: 00007FF703FBD5CC
>   v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980 9: 00007FF703FC6317
>   v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327 10: 00007FF703FC6396
>   v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454 11: 00007FF7040F0637
>   v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55 12: 00007FF70416D826
>   v8::internal::operator<<+73494 13: 000002DCE045C5C1 <--- Last few GCs
>   ---> a[8764:0000027D750B35E0] 50004 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.7 (1427.4) -> 1394.5 (1428.9) MB, 2019.6 / 0.0 ms (+ 0.1 ms in 121 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 2060
>   ms) (average mu = 0.116, current mu = 0.020) a[8764:0000027D750B35E0]
>   52621 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.4 (1428.9) -> 1397.4 (1430.4) MB, 2599.6 /
>   0.0 ms (+ 0.0 ms in 75 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 2617 ms) (average mu = 0.056,
>   current mu = 0.007) al <--- JS stacktrace ---> ==== JS stack trace
>   ========================================= 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0000000482F5C5C1] Security context: 0x02cd6009e6e9  1:
>   registerBinding [00000129D11ABF11]
>   [D:\Bentley\DesignValidationUI\source\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\scope\index.js:~475]
>   [pc=00000004834C6E80](this=0x029a59ccfe99 ,/* anonymous */=0x00983d4eaf59 ,/*
>   anonymous */=0x03ad79cd3b41 ,/*
>   anonymous */=0x0016e7b026f1
>
> ### retries!

Comment: this helped me. have to tried this  -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294252/angular-production-build-fatalprocessoutofmemory-error

Answer (score 0):

For prod builds setting --max_old_space_size=4096 will works, run following command

```
 node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```